# How to pass values from dynamically created gridview checkboxes to a crystal report?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Does anyone know how to pass values from adynamically created gridview checkboxes to a crystal report?Is it possible? I am using asp.net, vb.net and mssql. Here's my grid minus a few boundfields:

```
<asp:gridview id="grid" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" cellpadding="4"
    forecolor="#333333" gridlines="None" emptydatatext="No Products registered for this company...">
  <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" onclick="javascript:HighlightRow(this);" AutoPostBack="True"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <input id="chkAll" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" runat="server" type="checkbox" />
      </HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="aid#" HeaderText="AID#" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="brandname" HeaderText="Brand Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="exp_date"  DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HeaderText="Exp. Date" />
  </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in C#, but the concept is the same.  You need to loop over each row, find the checkbox, check if it's "Checked" and grab the Datakeys value.

```
        // processCount is just used to calculate the total rows Checked.
        int processCount = 0;

        for (int indx = 0; indx < GridView1.Rows.Count; indx++)
        {
            Control control = GridView1.Rows[indx].FindControl("Id");

            if (control != null && control is CheckBox)
            {
                var chkbx = (CheckBox)control;
                if (chkbx.Checked)
                {
                    string rowId = GridView1.DataKeys[indx].Value.ToString();

                    //Do something with your DataKey value.....

                    processCount++;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Zachary, but I am looking for a little more code linking my values with the report. (I am new to to Crystal Reporting)  Thanks!